# How to calculate the energy state correction for second order degenerated pertubation theory where the degenarcy is not lifted to first order?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

In Sakurai, there is a question (problem 5.12) about degenerated perturbation theory where the degeneracy is not lifted in first order. One is supposed to find the energy correction in second order for the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
H=H_0 +\delta H =
\begin{pmatrix}
E1 & 0 & a \\
0 & E1 & b \\
a* & b* & E3
\end{pmatrix}
\; 
\text{with} \;\;
\delta H =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 0 & b \\
a* & b* & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I've found the energy corrections to be $E^{(2)}_1 = 0$, $E^{(2)}_2=-\frac{|a|^2+|b|^2}{E_3-E_1}$ and $E^{(2)}_3 = \frac{|a|^2+|b|^2}{E_3-E_1}$.

Now I'm interested in how the state correction in first and second order $|n^{
(1/2)}$> would look like. I did a bit of research and found a blog article about that topic.

https://acollectionofelectrons.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/second-order-degeneracy/

The author explains how to obtain the state corrections in degenerate perturbation theory if the degeneracy is lifted in first order. It is not apparent for me how to generalize this for the case where the degeneracy is not lifted to first order.

How do I calculate the state corrections up to second order for $H$ or in general ?

Comment: The key point of degenerate perturbation theory is to identify a set of "good states" of the unperturbed Hamiltonian that remain eigenstates after the perturbation is applied. The same basic idea applies here, but "one level down." In other words, you want to find a combination of the eigenstates including corrections to 1st order, that are still eigenstates when you solve the 2nd order equations. Does this help?

Comment: Ok, lets say a=a*=b=b* (just for simplicity), then the matrix I have to diagonalize to get the "good states" becomes $\frac{a}{E^{0}_1 - E^{0}_3}}$ times
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
which has the eigenbasis (1,1) & (1,-1). So, if I understand you right you say that the state corrections look like 
$|1/2^{(1)}> =\frac{a}{E^{0}_1 - E^{0}_3}(|1^{(0)}>\pm |2^{(0)}>) + \frac{a}{E^{0}_1 - E^{0}_3}|3^{(0)}>$ ?

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow actually. How were you able to compute the second order corrections to the energy $E_{1,2,3}^{(2)}$ in the question without knowing the corrections to the states to first order? What' I'm saying is that at first order, you should find a 2d degenerate subspace of eigenstates. To compute the second order corrections to the energy, you want to identify "good" states in this 2d space that remain eigenstates at second order.